# Look for a string in URL using test and location.href

Tags: javascript, php, regex, joomla

I'm trying to create a code that will show a text only if the word "obyn" is in the URL.

```
     <p id="p1">Hello World!</p>

       <script>
     function myFunction() {
         var str = self.location.href;
         var patt = new RegExp("obyn");
         var res = patt.test(str);
         return res;
     }

     if(myFunction()){
         document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "New text!";
      else{
         document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "Text 2";
      }  
     </script>
```

EDIT:
After making changes as suggested below, it still doesn't work. It always shows **"Hello World!"**.

Comment: is it me, or are you trying to excute a Javascript function with a PHP command?

Comment: You know that you cannot get the result of the javascript myFunction() function in PHP (without something like ajax), do you?

Comment: Also, `myFunction == true` only checks if the function is true. Which it is - the function exists. Use myfunction() to test againstthe result of that function.

Comment: As you guys can tell, i'm not good with this.. When i add the myFunction() i get error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function myFunction()

Comment: @StefanTrailovic the hints of @sxefloden and  @stribizhev are not correct because they didn't recognized that you mixed php and javascript. The hints are valid if your `if()...` is written in javascript not in php.

Comment: I've done changes as suggested, but still not working.. Any idea?

Comment: @steven nope, not true. `if (myFunction == true)` will evaluate true in javascript, regardless of the return value of the function. Without parenthesis the function isn't called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't execute your Javascript function from PHP,

The solution here is to do what you want only with your Javascript. (You can append 'This text' or "Nope" just like you did in PHP but with DOM or JQuery)

you should add this line at the end of your function :

`return res;` //returns true or false

then you can just test it like

```
 if(myFunction()){
    var node = document.createElement("A");//This creates something like "<a> </a>                 
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("This text"); //This creates a text    
    node.appendChild(textnode);//Then it appends your text to the div so "<a>This text</a>"    
    document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(node); //Then you can append it to your div "<div id="myDiv> </div> like this 
 }
 else{
     //try to do the same job for "Nope" to understand the code I just gave you :)
 }
```

Comment: Could you show me an example code? Not familiar with them at all.

Comment: please not offence but, If you are not familiar then start with the basics.

Comment: I just added some code to get you started, also you should read some about DOM and JQuery, have a good day

Comment: I've done changes but still the same, check original question for edit. @Daniel

Comment: You have to run your function, just type var testRegex=myFunction(); on your javascript and change the "myFunction()" on the ifs to testRegex

Comment: I missed a "}" on the if. But thank you for all the help! :-)